# How Do I set the image to stay in place when I zoom in and zoom out?

Tags: html, css, image, css-position

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKzCu.png)I'm having this problem where my image on my website is moving to the right of my screen when I zoom out and zoom in. How can I get to stay stationary on the screen?

Here's the CSS code for the image...

```
.logo {

    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    position: absolute; TOP: 60px; RIGHT: 230px;
    position: auto;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Can you post an example image(s) of what you would like to achieve?

Comment: Im afraid it would let me because I just made an account.

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying the amount of pixels that your image needs to be away from the right border. Replace it by a relative size, like `Right: 50%;` so that, when resizing or zooming in or out, the distance from the right border is responsively recalculated.

Comment: That helped part of my problem, but when I zoom in or out that certain image moves to the left or right when I zoom in or out. How can I lock it in place so it doesn't do that?

Comment: I'm afraid, I don't unterstand the issue. Maybe you can show us an image where the problem gets clearer or, even better, a complete, minimal code example?

Comment: It wont let me put in image because I just made an account for StackOverflow sorry

Answer (score 0):

Use [Viewport-percentage lengths](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length) units instead of pixels.

> Viewport-percentage lengths define the `<length>` value relative to
> the size of the visible portion of the document.

Something like this:

```
.logo {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 5vh; 
    right: 15vw;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me :

```
background-position: top; /* or center */
```